# Stringify Keys Error

Tags: ruby, arrays, activerecord, methods, hash

Here is my method:

```
  def self.unique_coasters_this_year(year)
    counter = 0
    all.each do |c|
      years = new Array
      c.rode_on.each do |date, count|
        years << (Date.parse date).year
      end
      if years.include?(year)
        counter += 1
      end
    end
    counter
  end
```

When running it I get this stringify_keys error:

> oMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for Array:Class from
>   /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:69:in`
>   assign_attributes' [97] pry(main)>

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this runs at *all*, since that's not how you create a new object. And it's unusual to not just use `years = []`. Why aren't you just using `collect`? In any case, are you sure the error happens in the code you show? What line is line 69?

Comment: Looks like this runs b/c its a class method passing `Array` to `self.new`. The initialize method of the class is trying to call `stringify_keys` on the hash it expects to be passed in. A confusing error for someone new to ruby! Just to be super clear, the syntax for initialization in ruby is `Array.new` not `new Array`

Comment: @Alex.Bullard Ah, it's in a class method; missed that. I was staring at that and couldn't figure out what was happening. I'd make that an answer. (And use `collect` ;)

Comment: Ah ha. Yeh, my bad, Language confusion between this and PHP. Changed to use `years = []` and will look at `collect`. Thanks!